# How to change conda python version to a manually compiled python version?

Tags: python, conda

I am running a raspberry pi with an armv7l image, and I want to use python 3.8 as my base version. This image of raspbian comes with python 3.4 and python 2.7. I downloaded python3.8 and manually compiled it.

However, all previous version of python reside in /usr/bin and /usr/lib while my manually compiled version resides in /usr/local/bin.

When I run  `conda info`, the output says `python version : 3.4.3.final.0`
and when I run `conda search python` the output says `python 2.7.10` and `python * 3.4.3`.

My question is, how do I get conda to recognize the python version 3.8.2 that I've manually compiled and installed?

I've tried searching around the internet but the only answers I've found are ones in which you *install a new version* of python instead of adding a version you already have.

Comment: use virtual env in anaconda or in bashrc file edit default conda python path

Comment: Not sure this is possible. Conda is not supported officially for **linux-armv7l** platform and the project to support it (berryconda) looks like it went stale nearly 2 years ago, so the latest supported Python + conda is Python v3.6 and Conda v4.5.11. See [the **rpi** channel](https://anaconda.org/rpi).